# Install Opencart store in subdirectory with a Login in the root folder

Tags: opencart

hope all is well. I am trying to install Opencart (2.0.3) into a subdirectory (Ie. www.website.com/shop/) I want the root URL www.website.com to go to a Login page, where once a user logs in. It will redirect them to the /shop/ portion of the site and allow them to continue their business. I was wondering what the easiest way was to accomplish this. Would I install everything in the root folder, and then modify the .htaccess file along with the config files? Then how would i Make the login files work in the root folder? I tried installing everything first into the subdirectory /shop/... but then I get issues trying to figure out how to get files in the root folder to work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I decided to just load it into a subdirectory /shop/... how would I get the login pages to show up in the root folder?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, need to work with ajax functionality as below. In the index.php insert the following code and replace URL_WITH_SHOP with your urlshop. Then I have taken "shop" as sub-folder installation if it is different then replace "shop" with your sub-folder name:

```html
<script src="shop/catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="shop/catalog/view/javascript/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="content" class="col-sm-12 ">
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin: 0px auto; float: none;">
                    <div class="well">
                        <h2>Returning Customer</h2>
                        <p><strong>I am a returning customer</strong></p>
                        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div class="error"></div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="input-email">E-Mail Address</label>
                                <input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="E-Mail Address" id="input-email" class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="input-password">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" id="input-password" class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                            <button type="button" id="button-cart" data-loading-text="Checking login" class="btn btn-primary ">Login</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    $('#button-cart').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'shop/index.php?route=account/loginajax',
            type: 'post',
            data: $('input[type=\'text\'], input[type=\'password\']'),
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#button-cart').button('loading');
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#button-cart').button('reset');
            },
            success: function(json) {
                $('.alert, .text-danger').remove();
                $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');

                if (json['error']) {
                    $('.error').after('<div class="alert alert-danger has-error">' + json['error'] + '</div>');
                }

                if (json['success']) {
                    $('.error').after('<div class="alert alert-success">' + json['success'] + '</div>');
                    window.location = "URL_WITH_SHOP";

                }
            }
        });
    });
    //--></script>
```

Above is the presentation layer, now let's make the logical layer, go to **shop/catalog/controller/account** and create **loginajax.php** and paste following code:

```html
<?php
class ControllerAccountLoginAjax extends Controller
{
    private $error = array();

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('account/customer');
        $json = array();
        // Login override for admin users
        if (!empty($this->request->get['token'])) {
            $this->event->trigger('pre.customer.login');
            $this->customer->logout();
            $this->cart->clear();
            unset($this->session->data['wishlist']);
            unset($this->session->data['payment_address']);
            unset($this->session->data['payment_method']);
            unset($this->session->data['payment_methods']);
            unset($this->session->data['shipping_address']);
            unset($this->session->data['shipping_method']);
            unset($this->session->data['shipping_methods']);
            unset($this->session->data['comment']);
            unset($this->session->data['order_id']);
            unset($this->session->data['coupon']);
            unset($this->session->data['reward']);
            unset($this->session->data['voucher']);
            unset($this->session->data['vouchers']);

            $customer_info = $this->model_account_customer->getCustomerByToken($this->request->get['token']);

            if ($customer_info && $this->customer->login($customer_info['email'], '', true)) {
                // Default Addresses
                $this->load->model('account/address');

                if ($this->config->get('config_tax_customer') == 'payment') {
                    $this->session->data['payment_address'] = $this->model_account_address->getAddress($this->customer->getAddressId());
                }

                if ($this->config->get('config_tax_customer') == 'shipping') {
                    $this->session->data['shipping_address'] = $this->model_account_address->getAddress($this->customer->getAddressId());
                }

                $this->event->trigger('post.customer.login');

                $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL'));
            }
        }

        if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
            $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL'));
        }


        if (!$json) {
        $this->load->language('account/login');

        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

        if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
            $json['success'] = "Successfully logging in! ";
            unset($this->session->data['guest']);

            // Default Shipping Address
            $this->load->model('account/address');

            if ($this->config->get('config_tax_customer') == 'payment') {
                $this->session->data['payment_address'] = $this->model_account_address->getAddress($this->customer->getAddressId());
            }

            if ($this->config->get('config_tax_customer') == 'shipping') {
                $this->session->data['shipping_address'] = $this->model_account_address->getAddress($this->customer->getAddressId());
            }

            // Add to activity log
            $this->load->model('account/activity');

            $activity_data = array(
                'customer_id' => $this->customer->getId(),
                'name'        => $this->customer->getFirstName() . ' ' . $this->customer->getLastName()
            );

            $this->model_account_activity->addActivity('login', $activity_data);
        }
            else{
                $json['error'] =  $this->language->get('error_login');
            }

        $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('common/home')
        );

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_account'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL')
        );

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_login'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL')
        );

        $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

        $data['text_new_customer'] = $this->language->get('text_new_customer');
        $data['text_register'] = $this->language->get('text_register');
        $data['text_register_account'] = $this->language->get('text_register_account');
        $data['text_returning_customer'] = $this->language->get('text_returning_customer');
        $data['text_i_am_returning_customer'] = $this->language->get('text_i_am_returning_customer');
        $data['text_forgotten'] = $this->language->get('text_forgotten');

        $data['entry_email'] = $this->language->get('entry_email');
        $data['entry_password'] = $this->language->get('entry_password');

        $data['button_continue'] = $this->language->get('button_continue');
        $data['button_login'] = $this->language->get('button_login');

        if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
            $data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
        } else {
            $data['error_warning'] = '';
        }

        $data['action'] = $this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL');
        $data['register'] = $this->url->link('account/register', '', 'SSL');
        $data['forgotten'] = $this->url->link('account/forgotten', '', 'SSL');

        if (isset($this->session->data['success'])) {
            $data['success'] = $this->session->data['success'];

            unset($this->session->data['success']);
        } else {
            $data['success'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['email'])) {
            $data['email'] = $this->request->post['email'];
        } else {
            $data['email'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['password'])) {
            $data['password'] = $this->request->post['password'];
        } else {
            $data['password'] = '';
        }
        } else {
            $json['error'] =  $this->language->get('error_login');
        }


        $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
        $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
    }


    protected function validate() {
        $this->event->trigger('pre.customer.login');

        // Check how many login attempts have been made.
        $login_info = $this->model_account_customer->getLoginAttempts($this->request->post['email']);

        if ($login_info && ($login_info['total'] >= $this->config->get('config_login_attempts')) && strtotime('-1 hour') < strtotime($login_info['date_modified'])) {
            $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_attempts');
        }

        // Check if customer has been approved.
        $customer_info = $this->model_account_customer->getCustomerByEmail($this->request->post['email']);

        if ($customer_info && !$customer_info['approved']) {
            $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_approved');
        }

        if (!$this->error) {
            if (!$this->customer->login($this->request->post['email'], $this->request->post['password'])) {
                $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_login');

                $this->model_account_customer->addLoginAttempt($this->request->post['email']);
            } else {
                $this->model_account_customer->deleteLoginAttempts($this->request->post['email']);

                $this->event->trigger('post.customer.login');
            }
        }

        return !$this->error;
    }
}
```

This will help you.

[Download files and folders for above codes](https://webocreation.com/blog/login-page-redirection-in-opencart)

Hope it also help you

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks so much for your help! It is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The only issue I see is when it successfully logs in and redirects to the actual shop, the customer has to log in again. Its not remembering that you already logged in,

Comment: I noticed that when you log in, it will go to the shop page and ask to be logged in again, but if i hit the back button on the browser and log back in ,, on the original log in page, it will go through and now it will be logged in successfully through out the shop site.

Comment: I have tested at my localhost many times and it is logging in properly.
I am not quite sure how it is not showing in yours.
Have you setup all files properly.

Comment: I was using a debugging tool and got an error. "XMLHttpRequest cannot load www.shop.com/login/index.php?route=account/account, NO 'Access-Origin' header is present on the requested resource, Origin http://shop.com" is therefore not allowed access. I am trying to figure out what the issue is, but this is causing the login issue stated above. I thought it was a conflist with a VQMOD tha tI had in regards to allowing site access unless a user is logged in. but it still has the same issue with the vqmod uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the login page then here is the tricks, create index.php or index.html at root folder then paste the following code and change URL_WITH_SHOP in the code with your url with shop like "http://www.example.com/shop" :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="content" class="col-sm-12 ">
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin: 0px auto; float: none;">
                    <div class="well">
                        <h2>Returning Customer</h2>
                        <p><strong>I am a returning customer</strong></p>
                        <form action="URL_WITH_SHOP/index.php?route=account/login" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="input-email">E-Mail Address</label>
                                <input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="E-Mail Address" id="input-email" class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="input-password">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" id="input-password" class="form-control" />
                                </div>
                            <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The issue will be if the customer enters wrong username and password then it redirects to the actual login page.

Comment: That worked quite well, thank you. Is there a possible way from keeping it from redirecting to the actual login page if the username and password are incorrect? Thanks